# Dialog display with blank field assigned to variable in Mac Terminal?

Tags: macos, display, terminal

I want to make a display box that has a text box that the user can enter a number into that will later be assigned to a variable. How would I do this?

Comment: The low-tech solution, of course, is `dialog`, which you can install e.g. using Homebrew or MacPorts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open AppleScript Editor, enter the following and save as script:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    repeat while true
        set input to display dialog "Enter a number:" default answer ""
        if button returned of input is equal to "OK" then
            try
                return (text returned of input) as number
            end try
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

(we need to `tell application`, because otherwise `osascript` doesn't allow user interaction)

Then run like this:

```
$ osascript path/to/script.scpt
```

Output of the program is the number the user entered.

Store in `bash` variable like this:

```
$ foo=$( osascript path/to/script.scpt )
$ echo $foo
42
```

Comment: Store in bash? What does  that  mean and why do I have to do it?

Comment: @JShoe Well, what do you want to do with the value the user entered? Probably pass it to a shell script. That's why I showed you how to store it in a variable named `foo`. Also, it's "bash variable" -- the additional space around `bash` comes from monotype formatting.

Comment: You could just `tell app "Terminal"; repeat while true; display dialog "" default answer ""; try; return (text returned of result) as number; end try; end tell`.

Comment: @Lri Thanks, I used one or two parts of that.

Comment: @Lri, could you post that as an answer so I can see it's format?

Comment: @Daniel $ osascript path/to/script.scpt gives me the "$" is not a command error.

Comment: @JShoe Just replace `; ` with newlines, and maybe compile it in ASE to fix the indentation. `$` indicates the [command prompt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt), you're not meant to include it.

Comment: @JShoe Sorry about that. You'll often see `$` and `#` next to commands to execute: `$` indicated any command prompt, while `#` indicates you require root privileges.

Comment: JShoe: @Lri's code is shorter than mine and keeps the behavior the same. If you want to try his code, you need to add `end repeat` just before `end tell` at the end, otherwise it won't work. See the original version of my post by clicking the time next to *edited* to see all differences.

Comment: @Daniel thanks, then how would I have it change so if they choose 1, it turns $foo from 1 into 17, which is it's key code?

Comment: @JShoe I suggest you create a new question for that, if you want to do something else that a lookup table or a big if/else monster -- which are my only ideas right now. Remember to explicitly mention AppleScript, because its key codes aren't used anywhere else AFAIK. Also, 1 is key code 18.

Comment: @JShoe As Far As I Know