# If then statement using applescript in mac terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, code

What would be the code for:

"If $foo is one, then $foo should now equal 18" ?

Thanks

Comment: Didn't you want all values converted to their key codes? Or just `1`?

Comment: To others, FYI: This is a question following [this](http://superuser.com/questions/268424/dialog-display-with-blank-field-assigned-to-variable-in-mac-terminal) other topic. @JShoe: I think you need to explain more fully what you want to do here. AppleScript and Terminal/bash scripting are two completely separate things and your questions don't make a whole lot of sense to me, to be honest.

Comment: Is there a way to convert them to their key codes? I'm only working with 1-10 in the program I'm making.

Comment: `10` is not a key. Do you mean `0`?

Comment: Well yeah, but the input of my program is 1-10. It's going to open tabs in firefox. Tab 10 = command + 0.

Comment: Then I suggest `keystroke foo using command down`. That's why I keep asking what it is you want to do.

Comment: But keystroke foo when foo = 1 will give me s. First I have to convert it to the correct key code, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bash (command line):

```
if [ "$foo" = "1" ] ; then
  foo=18
fi
```

in AppleScript:

```
if foo equals 1 then
    set foo to 18
end if
```

---

Responding to the comments:

```
set foo to 5
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "Firefox" to activate
    keystroke (foo as text) using command down
end tell
```

You can probably append this to my answer to your previous question as-is, minus the `set foo` line.

Comment: @JShoe It marks the end of the block of code only executed if the condition is true

Comment: Do I need "foo as text"? Wouldnt $foo work?

Comment: `$foo` is bash syntax. This example is for when you add it directly to the end of the previous script. Or do you want to pipe the output of one AppleScript into another using bash, when you can just append one to the other? Replace any `return` with `set foo to` in the dialog script and it *should* work.